# I can't create a character device inside of /dev/pts/ even as root

Tags: linux, devices, mknod

```
sudo mknod /dev/pts/mytty c 0 9
```

> mknod: /dev/pts/mytty: Operation not permitted

How come I cannot create a character device file in this directory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devpts

Comment: The filesystem (devpts) doesn't support creating any files. Even if you're root, you can't do something that's impossible. Theoretically, it would be possible to overlay-mount that directory with another dir from a fs where you can create files, but that will break `/dev/ptmx` and any programs which create pseudo-ttys (screen, xterm, ssh, etc)

Comment: @UncleBilly any chance you could write that as an answer?

Comment: if programmatically, there's an example in the manual https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Allocation.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pseudo-terminal programmatically or using (already created) tools. As an example, here you create `/tmp/mypty` using [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat):

`socat pty,link=/tmp/mypty,waitslave -`

Then you can read from / write to this file.